# exim4 is not passing messages on to mailman via LMTP

Tags: email, docker, exim, docker-compose, mailman

I am trying to set up `mailman3` using `exim4` to run my email lists. If I try sending an email to one of my lists, the email gets delivered to the `exim4` instance, which then keeps trying to deliver the email to itself over and over again until eventually it aborts the process as it detects it is in a loop. At no point does it try to deliver the email to `mailman-core`, as far as I can tell in the logs.

I have tried to set everything up according to [the documentation](https://mailman.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/mailman/docs/mta.html) for hooking up the MTA to mailman.

My entire setup is using `docker`, so I am using the mailman [docker images and documentation](https://asynchronous.in/docker-mailman/). The internal networking works fine for everything, so it shouldn't be a problem with that. The only thing I can think of is that exim is not properly loading the configuration, but I don't know how to check this other than by sending it emails and watching to see what happens (and so far they just get stuck in a mail loop).

Here are the relevant sections in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
  pg:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: mailman
      POSTGRES_USER: "${PG_USER}"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${PG_PASS}"

  mailman-core:
    image: quay.io/maxking/mailman-core:0.2
    volumes:
      - mm-core-data:/opt/mailman
    depends_on:
      - pg
      - exim
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      MTA: "exim"
      MM_HOSTNAME: "mailman-core"
      SMTP_HOST: "exim"
      HYPERKITTY_API_KEY: "${HYPERKITTY_API_KEY}"
      DATABASE_URL: "postgres://${PG_USER}:${PG_PASS}@pg:5432/mailman"
      DATABASE_TYPE: "postgres"
      DATABASE_CLASS: "mailman.database.postgresql.PostgreSQLDatabase"

  mailman-web:
    image: quay.io/maxking/mailman-web:0.2
    volumes:
      - mm-web-data:/opt/mailman-web-data
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      UWSGI_STATIC_MAP: /static=/opt/mailman-web-data/static
      SERVE_FROM_DOMAIN: mailman.example.com
      HYPERKITTY_API_KEY: "${HYPERKITTY_API_KEY}"
      MAILMAN_ADMIN_USER: "${MAILMAN_ADMIN_USER}"
      MAILMAN_ADMIN_EMAIL: "${MAILMAN_ADMIN_EMAIL}"
      SECRET_KEY: "${MAILMAN_SECRET_KEY}"
      DATABASE_URL: "postgres://${PG_USER}:${PG_PASS}@pg:5432/mailman"
      SMTP_HOST: "exim"

  exim:
    build: ./exim
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      # exim4 needs access to the mailman binaries apparently
      # https://mailman.readthedocs.io/en/release-3.0/src/mailman/docs/MTA.html
      - mm-core-data:/opt/mailman/core
    ports:
      - "25:25"
```

Here's the exim `Dockerfile` (based on [`tianon/exim4`](https://github.com/tianon/dockerfiles/blob/master/exim4/):

```
FROM tianon/exim4

COPY 25_mm3_macros /etc/exim4/conf.d/main/25_mm3_macros
COPY 455_mm3_router /etc/exim4/conf.d/router/455_mm3_router
COPY 55_mm3_transport /etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/55_mm3_transport
```

And the exim configuration files are as follows (and I have checked their presence):

`25_mm3_macros`:

```
# Colon-separated list of domains served by mailman
domainlist mm3_domains=lists.example.com

# the LMTP host is the mailman instance running at mailman-core
# for the config of this, see mailman-core/mailman.cfg
MM3_LMTP_HOST=mailman-core
MM3_LMTP_PORT=8024

# exim needs access to mailman-core data, which we have mounted
# at /opt/mailman/core. This is configured in docker-compose.yml.
MM3_HOME=/opt/mailman/core/var

################################################################
# The configuration below is boilerplate:
# you should not need to change it.

# The path to the list receipt (used as the required file when
# matching list addresses)
MM3_LISTCHK=MM3_HOME/lists/${local_part}.${domain}
```

`455_mm3_router`:

```
mailman3_router:
  driver = accept
  domains = +mm3_domains
  require_files = MM3_LISTCHK
  local_part_suffix_optional
  local_part_suffix = -admin : \
     -bounces   : -bounces+* : \
     -confirm   : -confirm+* : \
     -join      : -leave     : \
     -owner     : -request   : \
     -subscribe : -unsubscribe
  transport = mailman3_transport
```

`55_mm3_transport`:

```
mailman3_transport:
  debug_print = "Email for mailman"
  driver = smtp
  protocol = lmtp
  allow_localhost
  hosts = MM3_LMTP_HOST
  port = MM3_LMTP_PORT
  rcpt_include_affixes = true
```

Comment: Seems like it's just not using the correct transport. To check what router exim will use for a given domain: `exim -bt name@example.com`. To fully see all steps exim goes through in determining how it will handle a message, use `exim -bv -d+all name@example.com`

Comment: You were right, thanks for that little command. Basically the problem was twofold, one with the configuration provided by that docker image, and the second by the ordering of the routers.

Comment: @GTF what was the problem in your configuration?

Comment: @SidVerma basically my routers were out of order, so the messages were never hitting the mailman router.